# Programmatically retrieving assembly version of a running service

Tags: c#, assemblies, version

I'd like to access to assembly version information of a service I "control" with ServiceController class. (ie. I'd like to display "2.3.1.23" ), however I can't find any information about retrieving assembly versions ... Is it possible at all?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify ... I only know the name of the service running on the local computer. I want to access the "FileVersionInfo" of that service (better said service exe), however I don't know where is that service exe located.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the version of any service exe. Assuming that you know the name and path of the service's executable, you might want to try:

```
FileVersionInfo versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(<path and name of service exe>);
```

You can then use the properties of the `FileVersionInfo` class to show the version number. Please note that this also works for UNC paths as long as you have permissions to read-access the file.

**EDIT**
To get the executable path and name if you only know the service name, you can access the Registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`. Search a key that matches the service name. Under that key, there's a value name `ImagePath` that contains the executable's name and path.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, and this would certanly work, however I don't know where the service exe is located ... I only know the name that is passed to the constructor of the ServiceController class.

Comment: Edited my reply to show you how to get the executable for the service.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ServiceController)).GetName().Version
```

Comment: I think the OP does not want to see the version of the .NET Assembly that implements the ServiceController class, but the version info for some exe file...

Answer (score 2):

```
 Assembly runningAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
 if (runningAssembly == null)
 {
    runningAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 }
runningAssembly.GetName().Version;
```

Use this code inside you service.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to get the assembly version from code inside the running service.